# How to print coordinates of a view in the Logcat?

Tags: android

I am trying to print the coordinates of the view in the Logcat, but the values shown for x and y coordinates of the view are 0,0.

I am able to print the values in the onclickListner method, but the values of x and y 0,0 outside the method.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public TextView textView;
public Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    int[] location = new int[2];

    textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    Log.v("location","value" +location[0]);
    Log.v("location","value" +location[1]);


    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int[] location = new int[2];

            textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Log.v("location","value" +location[0]);
            Log.v("location","value" +location[1]);

            textView.setText("Button location\nx = "+location[0]+"\ny = "+ location[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

I am expecting the log values for textView coordinates from the the statements before onClicklisterner.

Answer (score 0):

To print X,Y co-ordinate of the view there are methods of view like getLeft() , getTop(). which will return you the starting position of X,Y co-ordinate.

You can refer below link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View